# How to use SASS/SCSS with Phoenix framework?

Tags: phoenix-framework

Is there a way to use sass/scss for stylesheets when using Phoenix Framework? And if there is, then how ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Phoenix framework uses [brunch](http://brunch.io/) for the asset pipeline.

From the [docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets):

> Instead of implementing its own asset pipeline, Phoenix uses Brunch, a fast and developer-friendly asset build tool. Phoenix comes with a default configuration for Brunch and it will work out of the box, but it is very easy to bend it to our needs, add support for various script and style languages, like CoffeeScript, TypeScript, or LESS.

To add support for SASS, add 'sass-brunch' in your package.json in the project root as:

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "brunch": "^1.8.1",
    "babel-brunch": "^5.1.1",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "sass-brunch": "^1.8.10",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8"
  }
}
```

Then run `npm install`.

Phoenix framework also supports asset management without brunch as the default.

While creating a new project:

> mix phoenix.new --no-brunch my_project

will create a project without brunch configuration. You need to setup a system that can copy the built assets into `priv/static/` and also watch your source files to make automatic compilation on every change. Read the [docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets) for more info.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a working demo repo with the steps I took as commits:

https://github.com/sergiotapia/phoenix-sass-example

---

To use SASS/SCSS, you need to install the `sass-brunch` node package.

```
npm install --save sass-brunch
```

Then edit `brunch-config.js` so your plugins section looks like this:

```
// Configure your plugins
plugins: {
  babel: {
    // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
    ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
  },
  sass: {
    mode: "native" // This is the important part!
  }
},
```

---

Once you do that, any `.sass` or `.scss` files will work seamlessly.

Comment: By default, phoenix outputs compiled css and js files into the `priv/static/` directory. So be sure to check there to ensure everything is working.

Comment: `native` means: use LibSass, which is a C/C++ port of the Sass engine.

Comment: Why do you suggest using `native` as being the important part?

Answer (score 6):

Google got me here and @emaillenin answer didn't work (I'm using default Phoenix 1.0.4), so I had to find something else.

The trick is to do

```
npm install --save sass-brunch@^1.9.2
```

Apparently, `sass-brunch` broke something after 2.0 and it doesn't work anymore with the version of `brunch` shipped with phoenix.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just noting that this is no longer the case. As of now, the most recent version of sass-brunch [2.9.0] is compatible out of the box with the version of brunch shipped with phoenix. The commit that fixed it is [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/commit/d046399e1264614b2d6282ef3fefaab2ffbee6d9)

Answer (score 5):

Some answers here suggest to modify `brunch-config.js`, others `package.json`. For Phoenix 1.3 compatibility issues are resolved, it is possible to use both `npm install` and `brunch`.

Add `sass` to `brunch-config` `plugins` section:

```
// brunch-config.js
plugins: {
  sass: {
    mode: "native" // This is the important part!
  }
}
```

Add `sass` to `package.json` `devDependencies` section:

```
// package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass-brunch": "2.10.4" // check latest version on sass-brunch page
  }
}
```

Then

```
cd assets
npm install
```

Comment: Remember (optional) to update `config/dev.exs` to also watch *sass* files for live reload. Ex: `~r{priv/static/.*(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg|sass)$},`

Answer (score 4):

In **Phoenix 1.4** brunch was replaced with **webpack**.

Instructions which worked for me:
https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-1-4-webpack-4-and-bulma-bootstrap-4-sass/14354/7
and
https://andrewtimberlake.com/blog/2018/06/how-to-use-sass-scss-with-webpack-in-phoenix-1-4

1. Install `node-sass` and `sass-loader` in your npm project
2. Update the loader in webpack config: `{test: /\.scss$/, use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]}`
3. Rename `app.css` to `app.scss` (and other css files, including the import statements, e.g. `@import './phoenix.css';` to `@import './phoenix.scss';`)
4. Update the import in `app.js` to `import css from "../css/app.scss"`

Comment: This didn't quite work for me with Phx 1.4.10, Webpack 4.4.0. The value under `use` in step 2 needed to be `[
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {}
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {}
        }
     ]` (which is actually what's given in the second link you posted. With that change, it works fine.